# Is $(0,1]$ compact in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

Is s $(0,1]$ compact in $\mathbb{R}$?

Since 
$$(0,1]=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/n,1]$$
and there is no finite subcover, I assume it is not compact.

Is this argument correct?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. $(0,1]$ is not compact, for the reason you give.

Comment: That's a good example of an open cover with no finite subcover. Or, you can use Heine-Borel, which says that a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

Comment: Note that while one needs to say "open in $\mathbb R$" and "closed in $\mathbb R$", being compact does not depend on how the set you're talking about fits into a larger topological space. Whether $X$ is compact is simply a property of its topology, and we don't care is that topology _arose_ as the subset topology. So usually one would say simply "compact" rather than "compact in $\mathbb R$".

Comment: (When you're calling $(1/n,1]$ open you're already working in the subspace topology anyway).

Comment: @HenningMakholm ok I get it. Thanks. I have topology exam in a week. Greets from Spain

Answer (score 2):

Yes the argument you give is perfectly fine! If you want to be absolutely rigorous, assume there is a finite subcover and invoke the archimedean principle.

Comment: More straightforwardly, you can invoke the fact any finite set of natural numbers has a maximum.

Comment: @Hurkyl you're right. I guess I just said what felt most natural to me.